# Convert exiting website for mobile use?

Tags: css, mobile, mobile-phones

What's the best way to make an existing website fit for mobile devices(netbooks, mobile phones based on Android, Iphone, Blackberry etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it flexible.

You can detect different device widths with CSS media queries: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#device-width

Less normative explanation: https://mislav.net/2010/04/targeted-css/

Great blog post: https://webdesignerwall.com/general/the-wall-is-redesigned

The [CSS3 flexible box model](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/) can also be your best friend.

Answer (score 4):

Without going as far as implementing a mobile framework I would suggest taking advantave of [CSS Media Queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) which will allow you to serve up different css depending on the wdith of the browsing device.

A good start would be to look at the [LessFramework](http://lessframework.com/) which has taken all the hard work out the grid calculations.

Answer (score 2):

[Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) will also give you some nice out-of-the-box responsive functionality, meaning that the site's presentation will adjust based on the type of device and the size of its screen.

And I'd recommend checking out this [book](http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design).

Comment: In my company we use twitter bootstrap it really works on all the devices and consumes less developer time.

Answer (score 0):

Current now many tools available, but how to keep good user experience is the most important.