# convert web app to mobile application

Tags: web-applications, mobile

I have a web application developed in php which supports functionalities such login/signup post comment etc. How can i easily convert it into a mobile app? Is there any site/tool that would help me do it. Many sites can directly convert but they dont support the inner code of the site. How to do it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert exiting website for mobile use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412293/convert-exiting-website-for-mobile-use)

Comment: Some clarifications needed: 

* Do you want to convert the app or add a mobile skin?

* What PHP framework do you use? This can simplify the approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jQuery Mobile` or some other mobile UI framework to build mobile version of your app. Later you can use `WebView` or `Phonegap` to display your web app as a phone app.

Few references

- http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/mobile-version-website/
- http://mashable.com/2010/12/16/create-mobile-site-tools/

Comment: Thanks .. also if we give to any companies to develop a customized application, do they require the whole source code of our web application or what is the actual process?

Comment: You can do it in many ways, 1) Develop API's and build site using those. 2) You can use existing code and change the JavaScript and HTML part :) I should point out there are many other ways to do.

Answer (score 0):

First try developing the mobile site using jquery with php backend. Once that works fine you can easily bundle it with any thirdparty bundling app like PhoneGap.